# Macbook won't boot, possibly HDD issue

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, crash, java

I am posting this for a friend who is having this problem but obviously can't post this himself as his computer will not boot up. He started having problems after a video game crashed during online multiplayer. The game is Minecraft, which is written in Java. He was able to send me this from his iPad.

"Console generates a huge log about detailing how the java application stub crashed. So I shut down the computer, note, regular, controlled shutdown, not force shutdown. Then when I go to reboot, the HDD boots up, and makes its little boot up noise. The screen is the usual eggshell white. Then, it makes the HDD shut down sound, and the screen goes to black. I tried this three times, same result. Right now, I'm just waiting, hoping that it's overheated or something. Any ideas?"

Comment: I have had something like this (the computer not booting) before. I had to do a reinstall.

Comment: IMO, the game crashed because the HDD get broken. So, not the game/java caused the HDD problem, but the HDD problem caused the game crash - and therefore the HDD problem will remain after the boot too. The friend should try boot from external HDD (if have one) and run HDD verification from Disk Util.app (on the internal HDD).

Answer (score 1):

Wait a little bit, and then try booting in Safe Mode, as described in [HT1455](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455). Then, try opening Java Preferences.app in /Applications/Utilities and unchecking all of the versions of Java you have to disable them. If you can reboot without Safe Mode after disabling Java, you might want to try re-installing your Java game or Java itself.

Comment: Thanks, will try to pass this info on to the guy experiencing the problems.